# word wrap jquery listview item

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a Listview with items that has almost 100 chars, but i need to show the full text, how can i do that ?

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
            <li data-filtertext="Hola" data-theme="b"><a href="" >Hola</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="mundo"><a href="" >mundomundomundomundomundo mundo mundomundomundomundomundo  mundomundomundo  mundomundomundo mundomundomundomundomundomundomundo mundomundomundo</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="hello"><a href="" >hello</a></li>
            <li data-filtertext="world"><a href="" >world</a></li>
        </ul>
```

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/jupagose/eFvzC/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just modify the `white-space` property

For example

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
        <li data-filtertext="Hola" data-theme="b"><a href="" >Hola</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="mundo"><a style="white-space: pre-wrap;" href="" >mundomundomundomundomundo mundo mundomundomundomundomundo  mundomundomundo  mundomundomundo mundomundomundomundomundomundomundo mundomundomundo</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="hello"><a href="" >hello</a></li>
        <li data-filtertext="world"><a href="" >world</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Of course It would probably be better to avoid using inline styles, and you would probably be better off just adding a class to the list items you want to custom style...

Comment: Very tks, I have more control with your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `white-space
:nowrap` from the rules `.ui-li .ui-btn-text a.ui-link-inherit` and `.ui-btn-inner`

or override it with `white-space:normal!important;`

Not sure if that could cause sideeffects though in the greater application..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eFvzC/1/

---

If you want to avoid inline styles you could target directly the element based on the `data-filtertext` value (*for modern browsers*)

```
.ui-li[data-filtertext="mundo"] .ui-btn-text a.ui-link-inherit{
   white-space:normal!important;
}
```

Comment: Very tks it works perfect... But can i overwrite it only for an specific listview?